# What happens to an object when it passes through a portal?

Tags: science-based, physics, space-constructs, games

As in the game *Portal*, if we create two portals on two different surfaces and then join the two surfaces with the portals facing each other, as soon as an object passes through one of them, what would happen to that object? Where would it go, and what would be its state?

And what would happen after we separate the two surfaces again?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! Although very interesting question, it does not seem to fit scope of this site. I think it could fit to [Writers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) with emphasis on how to describe the process itself, because short answer to your question is: We do not know

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Curious_Fool*! You might be interested in some of our existing questions about such portals, such as [In 'portal', pushing interconnected portals on thin portal sized rectangles of material through each other?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/6849/28789) or other questions involving portals such as [What would happen if a wormhole disappeared while a ship was inside it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/88052/28789). You should [edit] your question to explain how the game mechanics work as not everyone may be familiar with the game.

Comment: If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about how the site works. Have fun!

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, if you had two surfaces pressed against one another with a portal on each surface, the portals would be inaccessible because they'd each be blocked by the other side of the surface they're on.

Comment: I don't understand how you insert an object if the two portals are facing each other

Comment: Not enough for an answer: Since a portal is (mostly) a "shortcut" through spacetime, two in that way joined portals would have a way-length of 0, so the "shortcut" would cease to exist. Nitpick: Two connected portals are really one portal, but each end looks like a single portal :)

Comment: @Raditz_35 presumably you'd insert the object into the portal loop, then move the two portals together.  Presume you have a vertical portal stack with one portal on the "roof" and the other on the "floor."  An object entering the portal stack would accelerate indefinitely, dropping from ceiling to floor in an endless loop.  If you lowered the ceiling, the loop would get shorter, and the iterations faster, up until you reached an infinitely fast and infinitesimally small duration of loop.  What happens when they touch, I'm not sure.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I can imagine a lot, but I think this is a question the OP has to answer so that people are on the same page.

Comment: Have you seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TZd95BCKMY) it may be educational.

Answer (score 2):

If the transfer is instantaneous you cannot move the portals during it. (Duh!)

If time is taken within the portal, the object gets trapped inside it. If the portals are close enough the loop closes and the object is permanently cut off from our universe. But this is unlikely as the wormhole should be too short for significant delay to happen without shredding whatever is thrown in.

If the transfer takes time on the outside, ie. it takes normal time for objects to enter or come out of portal, but insignificant time to pass between portals, which is most consistent with descriptions, you cannot push the portals close enough to each other since the head of the object collides with its tail.

This happens regardless of how you position of the portals. As distance between the portals approaches zero the area object uses on the portal surface approaches infinity. Which exceeds the actual finite surface area of the portal.

Answer (score 1):

## Portals within the game Portal have limitations to avoid this phenomenon

In the game portal the portals are immovable. They collapse when they are moved.

The reason for that is exactly to avoid unsolvable situations like this. If the portals were allowed to move relative to one another you could easily create even bigger issues regarding energy and spacetime than you already have creating a portal like.

So with the basic premise of your question "portals like in Portal moving towards another" you already created something else than portals like those in Portal as they do not allow this phenomenon to occur.

**That's why you can't really get any better answer than this. Your premise is not met in your question.**